# Loop to create bivariate/cross table

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop where I want get the frequency between column 1 and column 2,column 1 and column 3....till col1 and col30.

```
Col1 col2 col3
0        A     25
1        A     30
0        A     30
1        B     20
0        B     20
```

Output.

```
     0    1               0      1
 A   2    1         25    0      0
 B   1    1         30    1      1
                    20    1      1
```

Comment: People will appreciate if you share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to loop over columns and then `table` to calculate frequency

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) table(x, df[, 1]))

#$col2

#x   0 1
#  A 2 1
#  B 1 1

#$col3

#x    0 1
#  20 1 1
#  25 1 0
#  30 1 1
```

Or a shorter version using `Map`

```
Map(table, df[1], df[-1])
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), col3 = c(25L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(names(df)[-1], ~  cbind(df[1], df[.x]) %>% 
           count(Col1, !! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
           spread(Col1, n, fill = 0))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), col3 = c(25L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```